# How to run more than one test using unittest in pycharm?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm doing unit test for my project using unittest module. I'd like to do a class that has more than one test function for organization. Using Pycharm, sometimes it works, but not always.

When I change the name of the class function, the test may work or not (I know need to have "test" in class function name). For example, in the code below:

```
import unittest


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_func1(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)

    def test_classe_no(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the test, the console shows: `Ran 1 test in 0.002s.` But if I change the name of function `test_classe_no` to `test_class` it shows `Ran 2 tests in 0.002s`. If I edit some code, it can stop working. This happens only running in PyCharm, running in terminal (windows cmd) it appears to work. I would like to run directly on pycharm for convenience. What's wrong?

Comment: What's the result of `python -m unittest your_filename_containing_mytest.MyTest` when ran in the PyCharm env but from your Windows CMD ? (don't forget to replace `your_filename_containing_mytest` with your filename)